# Maximize area of quadrilateral given a diagonal.

Tags: geometry

I would like to know if it is possible to compute the maximum area of a queadrilateral with sides given by  $a,b,c,d$ respecto to some diagonal $x$, i.e., I know the  lenght of the four sides $a,b,c,d$ could I find the lenght of a diagonal $x$ that maximize de area of the quadrilateral? Or the lenght of a diagonal $x$ is fixed by the values of the sides?
My try is suming the area of two triangles and use the equation to the areas of a triangle;
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A_{q}&=A_{t_1}+A_{t_2}\\
&=\sqrt{s_1(s_1-a)(s_1-b)(s_1-x)}+\sqrt{s_2(s_2-c)(s_2-d)(s_2-x)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $S_1,S_2$ are the semiperimeters of the triangles, I am not sure that it is correct, or there are another way to do it. So
any help, advice or comment is welcome, thank you!.

Comment: Given $a,b,c,d$, the area is maximized when it is a [cylic quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral). Look at above wiki entry for the formula of maximal area and corresponding diagonals.

Comment: Your approach is correct and can help to find proximate optimum $x$ from plot $A_q$ as function of $x$. But if you need analytic solution, you may have better approach. Let use cosine rule $x^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos \alpha$, $x^2=c^2+d^2-2cd\cos \beta$, then $\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2}{2}=2B=ab\cos\alpha-cd\cos \beta$, where $B$ is known from $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$. Area satisfies $2A=ab\sin\alpha+cd\sin\beta$. Then $(2A)^2+(2B)^2=a^2b^2+c^2d^2-2abcd\cos(\alpha+\beta)$. $A$ will be maximum, when $\cos(\alpha+\beta)$ will be minimal, $\alpha+\beta=180$°. Then $\cos\alpha=\frac{2B}{ab+cd}$. Then put in $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was so helpful!